# Sudo su vs su linux

Tags: linux, macos, sudo, bsd, su

If I enter in the password to `su` when prompted, it doesnt work while `sudo su` does. Also, when a command is executed using `sudo (command)`, does sudo automatically execute it by root by default (since the man page says `sudo, sudoedit - execute a command as another user`

```
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~$ su
Password:
su: Authentication failure
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for michaelxu:
root@michaelxu-server:/home/michaelxu# exit
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's because `su` asks for password of the user you're changing into (which by default is root) while `sudo` asks for your own user account's password and checks if you are allowed to run the command.

When you run `sudo su` you are asking `sudo` to run the command `su` as root, which gives you the root shell. If you are using only `su` you will have to know the target user's password to have access.

Using `sudo` without parameters implies that you want to use root. If you want to execute the command as another user, try `sudo -u <username> <command>`

Comment: One other important bit of information to understand the related command `sudo su otheruser` is that `su` allows the root to switch into any users without entering their password, while non-root users that runs `su` have to input the target user's password. `sudo su` therefore runs `su` as root, which allows you to get a shell for another user without knowing their password (as long as it's allowed by sudoers).

Comment: So what would my root password be for the "su" command? How come it isnt the password I set in the beginning of the installation?

Comment: Because your distribution probably didn't set it. You can set a root password running `sudo passwd` (first provide your user password, then choose a new root password).

Comment: So at the moment there is no password?...so basically root is just an account that sudoers can use to make changes to root files?

Comment: not just that, there are many other services that have to run as root (check `ps aux`).

Answer (score 18):

`su` stands for **s**witch (or **s**ubstitute) **u**ser. With no user name given, it defaults to switching to root. It prompts for the password of the user you're switching to.

`sudo` is used to run a command as root (i.e., with root permissions), or as other users. It prompts for your password, and checks that you're allowed to use sudo.

When you type `su`, you're asking to switch to root, and the password that's requested is the root password. When you type `sudo su`, you're asking to execute the command to switch to root *as root*, so the password that's asked for is yours.

Answer (score 1):

...and to fix the problem of not being able to use 'su' alone, sudo to a root shell, and set a password for root, with 'chpass'.